# Allowing a user on windows domain to install updates to specific programs

Tags: active-directory, windows-domain

I'm quite new to Windows Domains but have set up one at home to have some small sense of control over the computers in the house. Each family member has a domain user so they can log in to each computer (but most have their own primary computer). So this is not for some gigantic corporation ;)

My kids use software like Steam, Discord, Origin, Epic Games, Faceit etc and many of them require me as an admin to be at home to enter my credentials to allow them to update. How do I go about to make a user able to run those updates for a given software? Is it enough give them write access to the folders the program writes to? Can I make it so they at least have to enter their own credentials when doing this? To avoid some hidden automated thing to write to folders.

Comment: You have to know where the updates install to, and allow that.

Comment: @music2myear Just a matter of giving write access to the user in question to the folder the application writes to?

Comment: Not just, but that's a start. You'll also need to allow registry edits to the keys in question. However, user accounts already have the ability to write to areas they control, and many applications have options to install as a user, only to the user controlled sections of the system, and these can be update by the user as well. The root issue is that, in the interest of management, you added an 800lb gorilla to your environment, which is not appropriate for small time setups. There are also family management systems that offer this without the extra stuff you've added.

Comment: @music2myear ok... I was hoping a bit for some kind of setting like setting a "run with admin rights" for a specific exe and a given user. Sure, this will work, but a bit more fiddling. But I guess I can set it up for the most needed programs, assign it to a group and give the kids membership of that group.